# $\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, residue-calculus

The following exercise is from the book of Churchill of complex analysis. Solve the integral
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^a}{(x^2+1)^2}dx$$
where $-1<a<3$ the book of complex analysis of Churchill suggests the indented countour: [image]

And also the book gives you the answer $\frac{\pi(1-a)}{4\cos(a\pi/2)}$.

Progress: I did $\int_\Gamma \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)}dz$ where $\Gamma$ is the region above. I already have
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=\frac{i\pi e^{ai\pi/2}(1-a)}{2},$$
$$\int_\Gamma \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=\int_{-R}^{-r} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz+\int_r^R \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz-\int_{C_r} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz+\int_{C_R} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz.$$
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C_R} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=0.$$
and
$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty,r\rightarrow 0}\left(\int_{-R}^{-r} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz+\int_r^R \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz\right)=(1+(-1)^a)\int_0^\infty\frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=(1+e^{i\pi a})\int_0^\infty\frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz$$
So I get
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=\frac{\pi(1-a)}{4\cos(a\pi/2)}+\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_{C_r} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz.$$
Where $C_R$ is the upper semicircle of radius $R$ with positive orientation and $C_r$ is the upper semicircle of radius $r$ with positive orientation.

So that tells me it must happen that
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0}\int_{C_r} \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2}dz=0,$$
but I haven't been able to prove it, I have tried to use Jordan's lemma doing a change of variable, integrating and using L'Hopital and I don't get that this integral converges to $0$. Does somebody knows how to achieve it?

Comment: Do you see that $\left | \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2} \right| \le \frac{r^a}{(r^2-1)^2}\sim r^{a-4}$ for $|z|=r >1$? What does that mean for the integral?

Comment: but $r\rightarrow 0$ and $a-4<0$ so $r^{a-4}\rightarrow \infty$. Or am I missing something? @MartinR

Comment: Oops, I misread your question. I thought it is about $r \to \infty$. But for $r \to 0$ you have $\left | \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2} \right| \sim r^a$. – It is a simple application of the [ML inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2291649/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \left | \int_{C_r}\frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2} dz \right |\le \int_{C_r} \left | \frac{z^a}{(z^2+1)^2} dz \right | \le \int_{C_r}\frac{r^a}{(1-r^2)^2} |dz|= \frac{\pi r^{a+1}}{(1-r^2)^2} \to 0$$
as $a+1 \gt 0$.

Comment: True, I was stuck wanting to use that last quotient you wrote $\sim r^{a-3}$ where $a-3<-4$, and I thought that quotient diverged.

Comment: @Luz That quotient is not $\sim r^{a-3}$, for it divided by  $r^{a-3}$ goes to $0$.